# Get properties of union type members as array

Tags: typescript

I have these union types:

```
type Foo = 'foo'
type Bar = 'bar'
type FooBar = Foo | Bar

type ComplexFoo = { type: 'ComplexFoo' }
type ComplexBar = { type: 'ComplexBar' }
type ComplexFooBar = ComplexFoo | ComplexBar
```

Is it possible to generate an array `['foo', 'bar']` variable from `FooBar` and an array variable `['ComplexFoo', 'ComplexBar']` from `ComplexFooBar`?

Edit: The arrays should be available at runtime.

Comment: Not without much additional work. During runtime all your type information is lost.

Comment: The arrays should be available at runtime.

Comment: Yes, your question is very clear on that. It is just that this is against the fundamentals on how typescript works.